# Possible to send a POX request, but receive a SOAP response from a service?

Tags: wcf

I want to send something like:

```
<GetColors>
    <Credentials username="test" password="test" />
<GetColors>
```

Once I receive the request, I want to read in the Credentials, verify it.  If it is verified, I will send back a soap response.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With build in stuff you can't. You can turn off the SOAP processing by either using REST service or custom binding with `MessageVersion.None` and you must build valid SOAP response manually like any other XML document.

Comment: That is the route I decided to take.  Thanks for the input.